# Keep getting ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, csv, file

I'm going through Kinder's and Nelson book *A Student's Guide to Python for Physical Modeling*. At the beginning of chapter 3 is information for downloading prepared data sets that can be used for practice. The data sets are in a zip file at press.princeton.edu/titles/10644.html. The data set I'm trying to use from the zip file is HIVseries.csv. The file contain 16 lines of code, as follows:

```
0, 1.061e+05
0.0831, 93240
0.1465, 1.6672e+05
0.2587, 1.5378e+05
0.4828, 1.188e+05
0.7448, 1.169e+05
0.9817, 1.0957e+05
1.2563, 1.1135e+05
1.4926, 74388
1.7299, 83291
1.9915, 66435
3.0011, 35408
4.0109, 21125
5.009, 20450
5.9943, 15798
7.0028, 4785.2
```

It is two columns of numbers separated by a comma. On pages 48 and 49, the book instructs me to load the data set and generate the data as an array with the following commands:

```py
import numpy as np

data_set=np.loadtxt("HIVseries.csv", delimiter=',')
my_file=open("HIVseries.csv")
temp_data=[]
for line in my_file:
    print(line)
    x, y = line.split(',')
    temp_data +=[(float(x), float(y))]
my_file.close()
data_set=np.array(temp_data)
```

When I run these commands I keep getting the following error:
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

I do not understand why I'm getting this error. The line.split command is clearly telling Python to separate the data using the commas in the file. Furthermore, I am entering everything exactly as the book tells me. How in the world can it tell me that there is only one value when there are clearly two values?

Comment: What Python and Numpy version are you using? Using Python 3.7.3, Numpy 1.16.2 and by copying and pasting the values you shared in a HIVseries.csv I was able to run it with no errors.

Comment: Using Python 3.7.3. I'm not sure how to check on the Numpy version. I left it out of the code I pasted here, but yes I did import Numpy, as np. Still getting the same error.

Comment: To check numpy version you can use `import numpy as np; print(np.__version__)`

Comment: Just checked Numpy, I'm using version 1.16.4. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that the reason of the error is that you have some extra line in the file without a comma and when arriving at that line, it throws the error you shared (on my end, when running the code with the text you shared it works, but if for example I append at the end some empty lines, it throws the same error).

To debug, you could stick an additional line before `x, y = line.split(',')`, `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and run the program again. In this way the program will pause before `x, y = line.split(',')` and give you an opportunity to run interactive code. You could for example see how each `line` looks and which one is throwing the error.

Comment: I just tried doing that. I don't know what it did, but it put the kernal into an unresponsive state. I couldn't scroll down and Ctrl-C couldn't stop whatever it was doing, so I had to restart the kernal. Still getting the same error. I've checked the file and confirmed that every line has a comma separating two values, but the program still gives me the error that it only sees one value. I'm getting very frustrated now.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. The data file had a few blank lines before the data. Python was reading those lines as if they meant something.

Comment: That was in my answer (;